# How to take 2 inputs in a single line in C language?

Tags: c

```
    for(i=0;i<t;++i)
{
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    scanf("%d",&brr[i]);
    a=arr[i];
    b=brr[i];
}
```

---

This code block is taking inputs in two separate line(after pressing enter),ex

12
45
How to modify it so that it take both the numbers in a single line(after pressing space),ex
12 45

---

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How to modify it so that it take both the numbers in a single
>   line(after pressing space)

Your code already does this (it already works if you pass "12 45" - you can put any amount of whitespace between them). If you want to you can use a single `scanf` call with something like:

```
scanf("%d %d", &arr[i], &brr[i]);
```

---

When using scanf it is a wise decision to check the return code, i.e. **the number of scanned elements**.

```
rc = scanf(...);
if (rc != 2)
    /* We scanned less than we expected! */
```